# Task list/Workflow list fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, web-part, list-form, uls

Suddenly when accessing my items in the Task list, I am prompted with the,

> "Sorry, something went wrong  An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this
>   page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator."

And when opening the Web Part Page Maintenance, I have this,

> ```
>   Web Part Title    Type                Open on Page?
>   Untitled          ListFormWebPart     Yes
> ```

In the ULS log I got the following as UNEXPECTED,

> 10/12/2016 10:23:21.01    w3wp.exe (0x1AF4)
>     0x470C  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open
>   database "TSP01_SharePoint_service_UPS_Profile" requested by the
>   login. The login failed.  Login failed for user
>   'domain\svcTSP01X'.

I really do not have any clue in why this suddenly is an issue. Tried to create a new site-collection, but still same issue, so it has to be an farm-issue or environmental-issue.

Why I am getting the error with the UPS database access?

> ***** UPDATE *****
>
> I think it could have something to do with the DispForm.aspx, but I am
>   not sure.
>
> ***** UPDATE II *****
>
> So, I am also having an extra web applikation on the same server, in
>   the same farm. So tried to create a page and work with the Task web
>   part. The issue was the same. So this is not web applikation
>   dependent, but a general farm-issue.

Any clues? Could it be the SQL permissions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, please check your SQL Permissions in SQL Server with your user account. It seems to be the permissions on the DB is not mapped correctly to the account.

Comment: The solution was the the SQL permissions. I gave the user Read and Data Access permissions to the UPS Profile DB and it worked. I am just wondering why this user need to run this DB. What has UPS with Task list to do.